# Get Name from ID via Active Directory Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Kind of hard for me to explain., but I'll try.

AssignedTo is a Guid in the database. I need to compare it to a list of Guids in the AD to get a name to show.

I have no problem doing the AD stuff. It's more of the how I do it and display the name in the view that's problematic.

Thanks for the help.

_

View: (Model is Entity Model of DB)

```
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.AssignedTo</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

Controller:

```
    private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Items.ToList());
    }
```

AD Code: (Not sure where to put this and make it accessible to the view.)

```
    public string GetUserFromGuid(Guid g)
    {
        ActiveDirectoryModel adm = new ActiveDirectoryModel();
        return adm.FetchContacts().Find(n => n.Value == g.ToString()).Text;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what the problem here is...this seems to populate and display just fine.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to access active directory or you don't know how to compare guids?

Comment: I don't know how to get it to display the name attained from comparing it to AD. I can't do it in a normal model and I tried using the method found here but it didn't work either: http://www.headspring.com/2011/07/how-to-add-a-method-to-viewbag-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Ber53rker - No where in your code do you reference your attempt at accessing active directory so how could we help you figure out why it isn't working?

Comment: @M.Babcock sorry, updated, thanks

Comment: @Ber53rker - Perhaps I've missed some new Entity Framework feature, but I am not familiar with a class named 'ActiveDirectoryModel'. What is this defined by? Can you verify that n.Value returns a string?

Comment: @M.Babcock ADM is part of System.DirectoryServices. I'm using FetchContacts (in a seperate class) to get a SelectList of all users. (.Value is the Guid of the user and .Text is their name, both strings.) That method compares the Guid values to get the right name.

Comment: @Ber53rker - I'd be happy to help if you could point me to anywhere that Microsoft references 'System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryModel', because it doesn't appear anywhere in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: What is the type of the `Model`? IEnumerable<T> where T is what?

Comment: Check [the MSDN docs on the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) - there is no `ActiveDirectoryModel` provided by that namespace - that must be something custom-made in your company. As such, we as outsiders cannot possibly help you here unless you can provide more information about that class....

Answer (score 1):

Adapt the view model you are passing to your view:

```
private MyEntities db = new MyEntities();

public ViewResult Index()
{
    var model = db.Items.ToList().Select(x => GetUserFromGuid(x.AssignedTo));
    return View(model);
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
...
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by creating a partial class.

```
public partial class Item
{
    public string AssignedToName { get; set; }
}
```

And then doing something close to what Dimitri suggested...

```
model.ForEach(x => x.AssignedToName = GetUserFromGuid(x.AssignedTo));
```

And then displaying it...

```
<td>@item.AssignedToName</td>
```